# Conditionally producing multiple values based on item value and merging it into the original stream

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a scenario where I need to make a request to an endpoint, and then based on the return I need to either produce multiple items or just pass an item through (specifically I am using redux-observable and trying to produce multiple actions based on an api return if it matters).

I have a simplified example below but it doesn't feel like idiomatic rx and just feels weird. In the example if the value is even I want to produce two items, but if odd, just pass the value through. What is the "right" way to achieve this?

```
    test('url and response can be flatMap-ed into multiple objects based on array response and their values', async () => {
  const fakeUrl = 'url';
  axios.request.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [0, 1, 2] }));

  const operation$ = of(fakeUrl).pipe(
    mergeMap(url => request(url)),
    mergeMap(resp => resp.data),
    mergeMap(i =>
      merge(
        of(i).pipe(map(num => `number was ${num}`)),
        of(i).pipe(
          filter(num => num % 2 === 0),
          map(() => `number was even`)
        )
      )
    )
  );

  const result = await operation$.pipe(toArray()).toPromise();

  expect(result).toHaveLength(5);
  expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd do it in a very similar way. You just don't need to be using the inner `merge` for both cases:

```
...
mergeMap(i => {
  const source = of(`number was ${i}`);
  return i % 2 === 0 ? merge(source, of(`number was even`)) : source;
})
```

I'm using `concat` to append a value after `source` Observable completes. Btw, in future RxJS versions there'll be `endWith` operator that will make it more obvious. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3679

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such combo - partition + merge.
Here is an example (just a scratch)

```
const target$ = Observable.of('single value');
const [streamOne$, streamTwo$] = target$.partition((v) => v === 'single value');
// some actions with your streams - mapping/filtering etc.
const result$ = Observable.merge(streamOne$, streamTwo$)';
```